# Has something changed making it harder to get 90 day supplies of routine meds?

Tags: prescription, legal, medications, class-schedule-of-drugs

When a doctor writes a prescription for 1 per day with a quantity of 30 with 2 refills, I have never heard of anyone having a problem getting 90 days of the medication at once.  That's 30 days for the original script plus 30 days for each refill.  30+30+30=90.  Simple.

Suddenly, pharmacies are giving people a hard time about this, claiming that the doctor needs to explicitly write the script for 90 days in order to get a 90 day supply.

Has something changed in the laws or regulations modifying how this has always worked?

Details: USA; non-narcotic, non-addictive routine meds like levothyroxin sodium.

Answer (score 2):

There are many factors that play a role in not allowing you to fill all the refills at once.

1- a typical insurance will pay for your medication and will not pay again until 2-3 days before you run out. (Insurance polices)

2- pharmacy systems do not allow the pharmacist to fill a medication on a patient profile more than once a day even if you do not use your insurance. (Company polices and systems)

3- to track your compliance with your medication and ensure that you are taking your medication correctly. (Pharmacist decision)

4- refills exist to limit the number of tablets you can take in an amount of time. Otherwise, the doctor could have given you all pills at once. (Common sense!)

5- other insurance policies such as, insurance want you to go on mail order after your first 30 days supply, insurance will only pay for 30 days supply at a time, you have exceeded the maximum dose for the medication per 30 days supply (Insurance policies)

Sincerely,
Pharmacist intern with 3 years of experience

Comment: Here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283). Also, you do not reference which health care system (USA, Canadian, etc) you are addressing.

Comment: @JohnP this is experience. I am my own reference. I would use a reference if It was a scientific question.

Comment: Although experience isn't usually accepted as a reference here, this is a difficult one because it's probably impossible to find anything published on the constantly changing and often irrational policies of medical insurance companies in the US. They often intentionally make it difficult to even determine what their policies actually are because that makes it difficult to challenge them. So I would accept "experience" as a source on this question if you actually specified what your experience is. I think you need to add that. (My opinion only -- mods may disagree.)

Comment: I'd go with the mods on this - there must be some source of information about this, such as [this one](https://www.pharmacy.texas.gov/consumer/broch4.asp). Furthermore, the OP has given a specific medicine - levothyroxine sodium -  a case where I disagree with your point No 3 - it's a medication taken chronically, patients mostly know how to use it and they don't visit their endocrinologist every 2 months, nor do they, in normal circumstances, do TSH and other analysis that often.

Comment: @Lucky there are no laws about this. This is pharmacy and insurance policies. Maybe there are state laws about this, but the Op did not mention a specific one. The question is actually very broad and can lead to multiple reasons of why he did not get his 90 days supply from a 30 days supply with 2 refills. I am not looking to have my answer accepted. I just want to put it out there until a better answer from someone else proves me wrong.

Comment: @Lucky I have to agree with shnisaka here. My own insurance carrier, one of the major US companies, has various rules they apply as to when I can and can't refill prescriptions. I can't find those rules anywhere in my subscriber info or on their web site, and they're certainly not state law. For example, they won't refill a prescription until 2-3 days before the last one runs out, even if you're going to be traveling. For a business trip I had to call them to get an early refill, and even then they only authorized 5 days' worth to get me through the trip instead of the full 30 days.

Comment: And no, it wasn't a controlled substance.

Comment: @CareyGregory I actually didn't realize that insurance companies could dictate such policies (I'm not in the US) especially without clear guidance provided by legislation. For me a prescription is a way of communication between a pharmacist and a physician in the fist place and after that a proof that insurance has to cover some expenses. So, I'll stipulate that the part of the answer about insurance is OK, but I cannot believe that anywhere in the world the pharmacist has the right to decide for you if you are going to save money or time (and I am a pharmacist myself).

Comment: @lucky deleted that point to make the answer more universal. In retail, pharmacist gets paid hourly and most of the time wants the best for his/her patients. If you fill a prescription and I notice that It is cheaper to give you 30 days than 90 days.. I would give you the 30 days.. it is a good customer service.

Comment: @Lucky There are many aspects of the American health care "system" that would be difficult for non-Americans to believe. Way off topic to discuss but trust me, it's broken in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

[90-day supplies are dominated by mail order pharmacies](http://www.drugchannels.net/2015/06/the-90-day-at-retail-boom.html).

[image: 90 day scripts 2010 vs 2014]

*According to the [PBMI’s 2014-2015 Prescription Drug Benefit Cost and Plan Design Report](http://reports.pbmi.com/report.php?id=10), 61% of employers allowed community pharmacies to fill 90-day prescriptions for maintenance medications.*

[image: Page 12 from http://reports.pbmi.com/report.php?id=10]

This means that although the gap between retail and mail order is closing, there's still a restriction in being able to fill 90-day locally based on the employer's insurance policy.

Comment: Any reason for the -1. I edited my answer substantially, so please review again.

Comment: I don't see a reason for a downvote either. Good answer. +1